# Flutter matrix gesture get size and position

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using with matrix_gesture_detector: ^0.1.0, after zoom in or zoom out, rotate,...

And i need to know the position and size of the widget. Is there anyway to do that.

I tried with globalkey but it only get the size the first time widget created.

[image: Size and position?]

Using matrix to get size and position

[image: Size and position?]

Please help!
Thanks in advance!!!

**UPDATE:**

This is my code

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (ctx, constraints) {
      Size s = constraints.biggest;
      double side = s.shortestSide * 0.666;
      matrix.leftTranslate((s.width - side) / 2, (s.height - side) / 2);
      TweenSequence colorTween = TweenSequence(
        [
          TweenSequenceItem(
                  tween: ColorTween(begin: color0, end: color1), weight: 1),
          TweenSequenceItem(
              tween: ColorTween(begin: color1, end: color2), weight: 1),
        ],
      );
      Tween radiusTween = Tween<double>(begin: radius0, end: side / 2);
      return MatrixGestureDetector(
        onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
          matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, null);

      var angle = MatrixGestureDetector.decomposeToValues(m).rotation;
          double t = (1 - cos(2 * angle)) / 2;

          radius = radiusTween.transform(t);
          color = colorTween.transform(t);
          notifier.value++;
        },
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          color: Color(0xff444444),
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: notifier,
            builder: (ctx, child) {
              return Transform(
                transform: matrix,
                child: Container(
                  key: _key,
                  width: side,
                  height: side,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: color,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white30,
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'you can move & scale me (and "rotate" too)',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: Theme.of(ctx).textTheme.display1.apply(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: you have `transform: matrix` so use `MatrixUtils.transformRect` to get "transformed" `Rect`

Comment: @pskink how can i get rect of the widget?

Comment: `Offset.zero & renderBox.size`

Comment: @pskink did i do it correct
`MatrixUtils.transformRect(matrix, _key.currentContext.findRenderObject().paintBounds).size`

Comment: @pskink sorry, i was new to this, i update my code above, can you tell me more, please! Thanks!